# which is the right way to connect couchbase in C#

Tags: c#, couchbase

I referred the document and it says

**Get the client library by using one of the following methods:**

- Download the zip file from here.
- Run the following command in the NuGet package manger console

I installed via **NuGet package manger console**

```
var client = new CouchbaseClient();
```

I didn't get reference for this class `CouchbaseClient;`

Am i doing wrong or how to rectify this ?

**And the code which is working for me is ,**

```
  Cluster objCluster = new Cluster();;
  IBucket objBucket = objCluster.OpenBucket();
  var returnVal = objBucket.GetDocument<dynamic>("strKey").Content;     

  //For upserting
  objBucket.Upsert(strkey, objDoc);
```

This is working for me.

**Problem in this is :**

All the inserts are falling into default bucket.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="couchbase">
      <section name="bucket-1" type="Couchbase.Configuration.CouchbaseClientSection, Couchbase"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <couchbase>
    <bucket-1>
      <servers bucket="default">
        <add uri="http://10.0.0.1:8091/pools/default"/>
      </servers>
    </bucket-1>
  </couchbase>
</configuration>
```

In that **bucket="default"** i changed default to other bucket. Still couldn't succeeded.

Please clarify me in two things:

1. What dll i need to use
2. And in the configuration what exactly i need to change ?

   **UPDATE :**

If i removed the dll added via nuget and added via the one present in zip that class is coming.
But Still didn't succeeded in the config part and also why the change in nuget and the package.

Which one to follow ? The document is explained with dlls in zip.

Comment: in addition to the answer read on this bug reported: https://forums.couchbase.com/t/getbucket/1350

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## NuGet and dll

`CouchbaseClient` is from older versions of the SDK (< 2.0). Latest NuGet package is indeed version 2+.
The snippet of code you provided is ok using SDK 2.0.

Where is the documentation you referred to? Where did you download the zip?

## Client configuration and connecting to a non-default bucket

I'm not entirely sure about the client configuration's schema, but I don't think what you did does anything. `OpenBucket()` always opens the "default" bucket (hardcoded), and you should use `OpenBucket(BucketName, BucketPassword)` to open a different one.

Also, for the cluster to take your App.config into account at all, it must be created using the constructor that takes the config section as a parameter: `new Cluster("couchbase/bucket-1");`. This is usually useful for bootstrapping configuration ( tags) and choosing different ports / activating SSL, since the default constructor will only try to connect on localhost.

See [the test configuration](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-net-client/blob/master/Src%2FCouchbase.Tests%2FApp.config) for examples.

Comment: Hi Simson Thanks for you reply. I figured it the config problem.And  the zip link is available in the document provided by couchbase [link](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-sdk-net-1.3/)

Comment: And i made stupid mistake by referring old docs and installing new binary from nuget..

Sorry for wasting ur time ...

Comment: It happens, no problem ;)